# how to check the entered value should be greater than previously entered value in DB using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check  entered value should be  greater than previously entered value in DB using mysql.

Ex: Employee Table:

```
id   age
1    23
2    25
3    27
```

In this above example I will add a new value called '24'  query should return an error that it should be greater than the previous value 27

Comment: Share some code you implemented please. Did you write it as a trigger or inside stored-procedures or something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple task btw, you should be able to do it.

Basically is like this below:

```
$new_input = 'your new number';

$sql_stmt = "SELECT age FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql );

if($row [age] < $new_input){
    //new input is larger
} else {
    //new input is lower
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind SO is not a free software writing site my friend

Answer (score 0):

Fire a query select max(age) from employee [[correct for SQL syntax]], then compare with the value being inserted. Do this in your code, or better in a store procedure.

Comment: He ask for last input, so I guess should get the latest id.